# How to improve sequential promises execution and force fulfillment

Tags: javascript, axios, promise, svelte, sveltekit

This code is being used in a Sveltekit web application.
In the first step I get a user jwt token from an api like : *dashboard.example.com/auth/local* 
and in the second step I'm using the response of the first api call to get full information from an api endpoint like this : *example.com/api/users/token*

This is an endpoint in an Sveltekit application:
[image]

```
import { json as json$1, error } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import axios from 'axios';
import md5 from 'md5';
import { SITE_ADDRESS } from '$lib/Env';
let userToken;


/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').RequestHandler} */
export async function POST({ request }) {
    const bodyData = await request.json();
    let identifier = bodyData.data.identifier;
    let password = bodyData.data.password;
    let loginToken = bodyData.data.loginToken;

    let newLoginToken = md5(identifier + password + process.env.SECURE_HASH_TOKEN);

    let dataResult = await axios
        .post(`${import.meta.env.VITE_SITE_API}/auth/local`, {
            identifier: identifier,
            password: password
        })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.data;
        })
        .then((response) => {
            let userSummaryData = response;

            userToken = md5(
                userSummaryData.user.username + userSummaryData.user.id + process.env.SECURE_HASH_TOKEN
            );

            let userCompleteData = axios
                .post(`${SITE_ADDRESS}/api/users/${userToken}`, {
                    data: {
                        userID: userSummaryData.user.id,
                        username: userSummaryData.user.username
                    }
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    return {
                        userJWT: userSummaryData.jwt,
                        userSummary: userSummaryData.user,
                        userFullSummary: response.data.userFullSummary
                    };
                });
            return userCompleteData;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // console.log(' ---- Err ----');
        });

    if (dataResult && newLoginToken == loginToken) {
        return json$1(
            {
                userJWT: dataResult.userJWT,
                userSummary: dataResult.userSummary,
                userFullSummary: dataResult.userFullSummary
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0, no-store'
                }
            }
        );
    } else if (dataResult && newLoginToken != loginToken) {
        throw error(400, 'Something wrong happened');
    }
    throw error(401, 'Something wrong happened');
}
```

This code is work perfectly in localhost. But when I test it on host I get error 401.
and the **question** is :

1. Why this works on localhost but doesn't work on the server?
2. How can I improve this kind of promises (I'd like to use the response of the first api call in the second api call and return both
   as a result)

Comment: Are you sure you're meant to be nesting the request payload within the `data` property of an object? Also, are you sure you're meant to be using the token in the URL path? JWTs are usually set into request headers

Comment: @Phil Yes. I'm forced to use a token in the URL path; As I've mentioned it works on local machine but when I upload it to server I get error 401

Comment: @rich-harris Could you please help to solve this ?